# Is there a good replacement finder scope for the Celestron 127EQ?

Tags: telescope, newtonian-telescope

I've had a Celestron 127EQ for a couple years now and have only used it a couple times.

One of the reasons I haven't gotten much use out of it is that when I do use it I spend all of my time aligning the finder scope. Every time I so much as breath on it the alignment is gone.

It already takes me a good while to line the scope up once and then as soon as I try to target something with it I inevitably brush some part of my face against the finder scope and have to start over with the alignment.

I'm happy to buy a new mount and/or finder scope, I just have no idea what to get that won't be just as bad.

Comment: The way the finder's connected to the tube looks non-standard. You may need to buy a finder shoe and screw it onto the tube before putting a new finder on there. Alternatively, get yourself a Telrad - a non-magnifying sight which projects concentric red circles on your view of the sky - it comes with a base with adhesive pads which can be stuck on the tube.

Comment: Rigel Systems QuikFinder is another (smaller)  unit power reflex red dot  type finder.  mechanically these tripods are very spindly. if you may be able to improve it if you are "handy". they also sell  Sorbathane pucks to put under the feet but that may help dampen vibration, ultimately it is a small scope , go for a wide field of view (low power eyepiece).